# python 3 can't recognize this character

Tags: python, loops, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm using python3 to read through a string and extracting certain elements into a list, using the following on the top of my script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import ast
import re
```

Works with all except for one character:   which in unicode is: U+C0545 and on the command line looks like:

[image: question mark in a square]

I would just like to skip this character, but the script can't recognize it. Is there any way  skip this character?

Comment: "script can't recognize it"...How??  You can make `s = '\U000C0545'` and it is just another character.  Show code that is failing.  It isn't an assigned Unicode character but it can still be processed like any other valid code point.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this should be taken as an authoritative source, but http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c0545/index.htm indicates that this is not a valid unicode character. Some systems may choose to represent it using some placeholder glyph, others may raise an error or behave in other strange ways.

In your python code, your best bet may be to handle the exception and do what is appropriate in the context.

Without seeing the actual source where the exception happens and the actual exception text, it's hard to guess what's really wrong.

Comment: it worked! i used anystring.encode("unicode_escape") to find unique name for the crazy unknown character, and from that identification skip that character

Comment: Having that character in a Python string in a source file doesn't make it an invalid Python 3 program as long as it is encoded correctly (UTF-8 by default).  It's just a code point in a string.  Also, for an authoritative source, use https://www.unicode.org/charts/.  It is not an assigned code point in the latest Unicode standard (13.0).

Comment: @MarkTolonen You're right, my assertion that the unused code point makes the source invalid was premature. I was extrapolating and guessing from the incomplete error description (should have asked for the actual code that fails and the actual error message). I'm editing my answer.